# (0x80131904): Login Failure

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am setting up a simple server, and am having some connection issues.

I know that there are others who have posted on this but I still cannot figure it out.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DormWeb
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                insertName.Text = ("Great job. You have figured out what your name is.");
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection dormconn = new SqlConnection
                ("Server=tcp:dormwebserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DormSQL;Persist" +
                " Security Info=True;User ID=Josh@...................onmicrosoft.com;Password=...........;MultipleActiveRe" +
                "sultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");

            {
                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.InsertFullname @Fullname", dormconn);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", insertName.Text);

                dormconn.Open();
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dormconn.Close();
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    insertName.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has been attempted with VS logged in with Admin account for server, and secondary admin account, as per instructions.

[image: vs]

https://ibb.co/Hg0x7Jq

[image: vs2]

https://ibb.co/SRKG4LT

I am logging into SQL management studio via active directory. Maybe that is my issue? Cannot get it to work when I opt in the active directory connection string.

[image: azurescreenshot]

https://ibb.co/xLQhpP1

Comment: Why are those `{` and `}` in the string? They shouldn't be there. Remove those and it will work.

Comment: @mjwills +  $exception {"Cannot open server \"jbu*******outlookcom.onmicrosoft.com\" requested by the login.  The login failed."} System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Comment: Your username or password is wrong. Have you tried using that username and password when connecting via SSMS (using SQL Server Authentication, not Windows Authentication)?

Comment: @mjwills So - I just tried the sql server auth login, and it is just a username, without the outlookcom.onmicrosoft.com behind it. Still login failed: any tips or pointers?

Comment: Have you tried using that username and password when connecting via SSMS (using SQL Server Authentication, not Windows Authentication)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove { and } around your user name and password.

In the connection string you get from Azure portal:

```
Server=tcp:jacksqldemo.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sqldemo;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

{your_username} and {your_password} are just placeholders.